# iframe not fully displaying collapsible menu. Set height to px but that causes issues when multiple tabs in menu are expanded

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to insert a page with a collapsible menu in an iframe but won't display properly.

I have tried setting a pixel height but it when multiple tabs are expanded the menu gets cut off at the top and you can't scroll up to collapse the top most tab. 
Without any height specifications the menu isn't visible at all.

```js
var jno = jQuery.noConflict();
jno(document).ready(function() {
    jno('#deliverlogic-iframe').iFrameResize();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.ondaguey.com/assets/templates/default/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.ondaguey.com/assets/templates/default/js/iframeSizer.min.js"></script>
        <center>
            <iframe id="deliverlogic-iframe" src="https://www.ondaguey.com/single.php/order/restaurant/east-coast-super-subs/32?REF=187&LIMITRR=32" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I just want the entire menu to be visible and when tabs are expanded for the user to be able to scroll up to the top of the menu.

Comment: Looks like https://deliverlogic-common-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js inside the iframe is not loading correctly

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't closed the `<center>` tag:

```
<center>
<iframe id="deliverlogic-iframe" src="https://www.ondaguey.com/single.php/order/restaurant/east-coast-super-subs/32   ?REF=187&LIMITRR=32" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Also, avoid using center tags as they are not supported anymore. You can read about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Use margin: auto; instead. Here's how:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_align_container